# translating quantifiers to english

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

domain: all people

$F(x, y) ≡ x$ and $y$ are friends

$I(x) ≡ x$ is a football player.

$$∃x∀y(F(x, y) → ¬I(y))$$

there exists a person $x$, for every person $y$, if $x$ and $y$ are friends then $x$ is not a football player.
I need to translate this to "natural" English.

"There is a person that is a friend with every person whose friends are not a football player."
when I say this, I feel that this sounds like $∃x∀y(F(x, y) ∧ ¬I(y))$.

Would this be correct? Can this be further simply expressed?

Comment: No, it's not correct.  It means "there is a person none of whose friends are football players".  A priori the person $x$ could have no friends at all (in which the implication is vacuously true).  Or $x$ could be friends with lots of people, so long as none of those play football.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Notice how your "There is a person that is a friend with every person whose friends are not a football player." contains two 'friend' relationships. Indeed, your sentence would be symbolized in logic as:

$\exists x \forall y (\forall z (F(y,z) \to \neg I(z)) \to F(x,y))$

So that's a good bit more complicated than the logic sentence that's given to you ... although that first part is very similar .. and that should give you a clue how to translate your logic sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"There is a person, whose all of his friends (if he has any) are *not* football players",

"There is a person, whose *none* of his friends (if he has any) are football players", or

"There is a person, if he has any friends, *none* of them is a football player".

In more details
$$∃x∀y(F(x, y) → ¬I(y))$$
says:

There is a person $x$, whenever some other person $y$ is his friend, that other person $y$ is not a football player.

Answer (score 0):

No, your translation is not correct for the reasons explained by @Bram28. Following are two English sentences translated from your formula:

- There is at least one person (in the world) who if is friends with others, they can't be footballers.
- There exists at least one person and if anyone is friends with him/her, the former can't be a footballer.

∃x∀y(¬F(x,y) ∨ ¬I(y)) is an equivalent formula. This could be translated into:

- There is at least one person such that people aren't either friends with him/her or aren't footballers.

∃x∀y(I(y) → ¬F(x,y)) is another equivalent formula. This could be translated to:

- If anyone is a footballer, then he is not friends with at least one person.